# What is the functional purpose of straining out shallots from a Beurre Rouge (Red Butter Sauce)?

Tags: french-cuisine, emulsion, shallots

Curious as to the reasoning behind why the French favor straining out shallots. Specifically I'm wondering if this is a purely textural thing, or if leaving in the shallots causes the sauce to have too strong of a shallot flavor. Usually I see shallots used when a recipe is looking not to overwhelm the dish with onion-y flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a texture thing.  Most classic French sauces are strained for texture and appearance reasons.  Also, some versions of beurre rouge have [more than just shallots](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/chef-thomas-kellers-beurre-rouge-recipe#chef-thomas-kellers-beurre-rouge-sauce-recipe) in them, making it more necessary to strain lest it be more of the chutney than a sauce.

If you don't care, you can mince the shallots and leave them in the sauce, per [Spruce Eats](https://www.thespruceeats.com/beurre-rouge-red-butter-sauce-995330).